# ANOTHER IndexOutofBounds exception

Tags: java, user-interface, indexoutofboundsexception

Alright, got through most of my problems(in Java...Today...)

In this GUI questionnaire, I manage to step through my questions, get my values...but for some reason, it is throwing an out of bounds exception during EVERY iteration of the loop... It is not actually causing the program to end or anything, but ask I page through questions and give responses, I see my console showing out of bounds errors for each count of the loop until the last question is asked.
If I comment out my calcPersonnelRisk(), which runs when the index counter is the size of the list, it runs through questions without ANY errors.  Confused because that method just assigns the values to my variables from my answers, and don't see why having that code in would screw it up.  I'm still in the infancy stages as a programmer, and still developing my ability to efficiently debug...but any input at first glance is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

```
public class ORMRiskCalculator extends JFrame{

private JButton yesButton, noButton, exitButton, enterButton;
private JLabel message;
private JTextField textField;
private JFrame frmOrmRiskCalculator;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
private int questionIndex;

private ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Integer> responses = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ORMRiskCalculator window = new ORMRiskCalculator();
                window.frmOrmRiskCalculator.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ORMRiskCalculator() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmOrmRiskCalculator = new JFrame();
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 102, 153));
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setTitle("ORM Risk Calculator");
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setBounds(100, 100, 650, 500);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    message = new JLabel("Create a new ORM Report?");
    message.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    message.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    message.setBounds(10, 10, 614, 109);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(message);


    yesButton = new JButton("YES");
    yesButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    yesButton.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    yesButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    yesButton.setBounds(80, 240, 200, 50);      
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(yesButton);
    yesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            questions.clear();
            responses.clear();

            getAnswers();
        }
    });

    noButton = new JButton("NO");
    noButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
    noButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    noButton.setBounds(80, 330, 200, 50);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(noButton);
    noButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(350, 275, 100, 50);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    enterButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14)); 
    enterButton.setBounds(450, 275, 100, 50);
    buttonGroup.add(enterButton);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(enterButton);

    exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");
    exitButton.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    exitButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 18));
    exitButton.setBounds(80, 425, 470, 25);
    frmOrmRiskCalculator.getContentPane().add(exitButton);
    exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        shutDown();
        }
    });
}

private void setupQuestions(){
    questions.add("How many mission personnel had less than normal rest?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel have an illness that may impact the mission?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are taking medications that may affect duty?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are scheduled to work longer than ten hours?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel worked greater than ten hours on the previous shift?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel swapped from night shift to day shift in the last 24 hrs?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are still in a training status or are a TEMP RCOs)?");
    questions.add("How many mission personnel are on duty during flight operations?");
}
protected void getAnswers() {
    setupQuestions();
    yesButton.setVisible(false);
    noButton.setVisible(false);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    message.setText(questions.get(questionIndex++));
    enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int r= Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().trim());
                responses.add(r);
                textField.setText("");
                if(questionIndex < questions.size())
                message.setText(questions.get(questionIndex++));
                else {message.setText("Done!"); calcPersonnelRisk();}
                //do finishing stuff, move to the next method! 
        }});


}//end getAnswers
protected void calcPersonnelRisk() {

    int lessThanNormalRest, illness, meds, lengthOfDay, previousDutyDay, crewExperience,
    shiftSwap, minManning;
    //probably better in this instance to use TreeMaps for future iterations of this program?
    lessThanNormalRest = responses.get(0);
    illness = responses.get(1);
    meds = responses.get(2);
    lengthOfDay=responses.get(3);
    previousDutyDay=responses.get(4);
    shiftSwap=responses.get(5);
    crewExperience = responses.get(6);
    if(responses.get(7) >= 4)minManning = 2;
    else minManning=0;

    PersonnelRisk pRisk = new PersonnelRisk(lessThanNormalRest,illness,meds,lengthOfDay,
            previousDutyDay,crewExperience,shiftSwap,minManning);
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
    message.setText("Your calculated personnel Risk is: "+pRisk.calcRisk()
            +"\n\t Run again?" );
    yesButton.setVisible(true);
    noButton.setVisible(true);


}

private void shutDown(){
    message.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 26));
    message.setText("Good bye!");//why doesn't this work? Sleeps, and closes, 
    //doesn't show my text message.

    try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);//also tried a wait(), notify(), but it seemed like the notify never allowed it to get to the exit command
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}//end shutDown method
}//endORMRiskCalculator
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i gave it a quick look but if i understand what is happening the yes button triggers the action witch clear the question list and call getAnswer witch tries to get values from question list so...

Comment: the clear function I added AFTER I was getting the error for if the user wants to run another calculation.  And currently it's only set up to allow the user to hit the yes button once to just start the questions then it's no longer visible

Comment: I see what you meant!  Yes, having the main create the array instead of creating the array in the getAnswers method, WOULD definitely cause some issues...fixed it! Now it isn't throwing the error until the very end.  (after I have completed the entire loop)

Comment: glad it helped. is this question closed? since we dont have the new code its quite hard to tell what is happening